# Biblatex style with colon separating authors and title

Tags: biblatex

I'm trying to configure my `biblatex` bibliography style to looks like this

[image]

But I don't know which style is that. Tried everything in `biblatex`. Right now `nature` style is the best one, but still not equal.

Below is my actual bibliography style (`nature`)

[image]

Which style is that? Is it custom? I think that URL color can be set with `url` package settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `nature` style is good for the other aspects just use this one to change the delimiter between authors and title:

```
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}
```

Starting from the `numeric-comp` style (on which nature is also based) you should use the following one:

```
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist]{nametitledelim}{\addcolon\space}
```

In this case, of course, you should also redefine other fields in order to meet your needs. Just to give an example:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{#1\adddot}
\DeclareFieldFormat[book,collection]{number}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{volume}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you also add: How to remove the & on the last author and use regular comma? Also how to declare the number of authors for `et al` substitution? Where can I read more about the valid `DeclareFieldFormat` fields?

Comment: 1) `\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addcomma\space}`; 2) Options `minnames`, `maxnames`, etc.; 3) `biblatex` documentation